# How to navigate different to view in JSONP request "callback" method

Tags: sencha-touch-2

//Below is my callback method which returns some response code.Now the thing is that i need to navigate to different view from the callback method.This logic i am using in userlogin. Provide me some solution that i can navigate to different view below i declared some code which i used to navigate to different view which works fine outside callback method not inside callback method.

```
 Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                url:'url',
                method: 'POST',
                callbackkey: 'callback',
                params: {
                    userID: user_Id,
                    password: password,
                    format: 'json'
                },
                callback: function (response, value, request) {
                       //Logic should come here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                },

                failure: function (response, request) {
                }
            });

enter code here
```

//Below is the cofig entry

```
config: {
        refs: {
            homepage:'HP'
        }
    }
```

//I am adding below code in success block but getting error

```
  var noteEditor = this.getHomepage();
  Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditor, this.slideLeftTransition);
```

Comment: I think you have a scope issue... put here your full sources. Not forget about what is the exception too

Comment: Yeah  olegtaranenko its a scope issue thank for the reply. Later i come to know its scope issue and i resolved the issue. The thing i did is i just declared  var noteEditor = this.getHomepage(); on top and replaced  Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(updateView,  {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'}); state with existence statement

Answer (score 0):

assuming you doing something like

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url:'url',
            method: 'POST',
            callbackkey: 'callback',
            params: {
                userID: user_Id,
                password: password,
                format: 'json'
            },

            scope: this,      /// fix handler scope

            callback: function (response, value, request) {
                if () {
                   //Logic should come here
                   var noteEditor = this.getHomepage();
                   Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditor, this.slideLeftTransition);     
                }
                else
                {
                }
            },

            failure: function (response, request) {
            }
});
```

you have to add a **scope: this** property to the ajax call.

Cheers, Oleg